# Obfuscated Maze generator

Tags: c, obfuscation, program-entry-point, maze

I found an obfuscated maze generation program from http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/maze_faq

```
int a[1817];main(z,p,q,r){for(p=80;q+p-80;p-=2*a[p])for(z=9;z--;)q=3&(r=time(0)
+r*57)/7,q=q?q-1?q-2?1-p%79?-1:0:p%79-77?1:0:p<1659?79:0:p>158?-79:0,q?!a[p+q*2]
a[p+=a[p+=q]=q]=q:0:0;for(;q++-1817;)printf(q%79?"%c":"%c\n"," #"[!a[q-1]]);}
```

i cannot understand why main(z,p,q,r) is used.what gets assigned to these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obfuscted, you are not supposed to understand it :)

This is an obscure way to declare integer variables. When you don't explicitely write the type of a variable in c, int is assumed. The part `main(z,p,q,r)` could also be written as `int main(int z, int p, int q, int r)`, but that would be boring. <strike>No values get passed to these variables when main is called, so at the beginning of the function they propably  uninitialized.</strike> z, p and q are initialized with the value of argc and the pointer addresses of argv and envp. The value of r should be undefined. But most of these values are immediately discarded. The value of the variable p, for example, is initialized in the for statement the main function starts with, and the variable z in the next for statement.

Is it legal according to ANSI to have a main function with four integers as arguments? Is it good practice to omit the type of int variables? Should you abuse function parameters as local variables? Who cares, in obfuscation it's correct when it runs.

Comment: i wanted to know if they're are initialized like argc,argv,envp. but they're not. thank you for the help.

Comment: @AtulVinayak Note that `q` is used before being initialized. So this still depends on `q` being assigned some non 0 value… Typically the pointer to the environment.

Comment: q is initialized with `q=3&(r=time(0)+r*57)/7`.none are initialized it seems.

Comment: @gen3 `q` is first used in the test part of the first `for` loop. This is *before* the `q=3&(r=time(0)+r*57)/7` part. Thus `q` *has* to be different from zero for the program to do anything.

Comment: sorry.yes you're right.but then it cannot be the envp right? it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gen3 yes it probably *is* `envp`. The only sense it makes is that it will most surely be not zero.

Comment: so its some nonzero value.its kept there just to make the loop work.am i correct?

Comment: thank you, @kmkaplan, I put that into my answer.